# OrderBy and OneToMany don't wok

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the entity Item which have one to many relationship with Bid

model/Item.java

```java
@Entity
class Item {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy(clause = "amount ASC")
    protected List<Bid> bids = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

model/Bid.java

```java
@Entity
public class Bid {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            generator = Constants.ID_GENERATOR
    )
    protected Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    protected Item item;

    @Column(
            nullable = false
    )
    protected BigDecimal amount;
}
```

I want to fetch add bids of an item and bids are ordered by its amount. But it doesn't seem to work as expected

persit data

```java
Bid bid1 = new Bid(item2, BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));
            item2.getBids().add(bid1);
            Bid bid2 = new Bid(item2, BigDecimal.valueOf(2000));
            item2.getBids().add(bid2);
            Bid bid3 = new Bid(item2, BigDecimal.valueOf(1500));
            item2.getBids().add(bid3);

//
            Object[] entities = {
              bid1,
                    bid2,
                    bid3,
                    item2,
            };

            for (Object entity : entities) {
                em.persist(entity);
            }

            itemId = item2.getId();
```

Select

```java
Item item = em.createQuery("select i from Item i JOIN FETCH i.bids b where i.id = :id", Item.class)
                    .setParameter("id", itemId)
                    .getSingleResult();

            for (Bid b : item.getBids()) {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
```

The output is

```
Bid{id=1000, amount=1000}

Bid{id=1001, amount=2000}

Bid{id=1002, amount=1500}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `clause =` from

```java
@OrderBy(clause = "amount ASC")
```

it should look like this:

```java
@OrderBy("amount ASC")
```

and make sure that you are using `javax.persistence.OrderBy`

Comment: That's very odd, because I have a similar setup, which does work, also a `OneToMany` collection which has `@OrderBy` and I have a query that I use on the parent (also with `EntityManager#createQuery`) and when I iterate over the collection, the objects are ordered according to the orderby value, not by their ids. The only difference that I can see, is that I don't have the collection lazy loaded and thus don't fetch them, maybe try with `EntityManager#find` since you are using an id anyways. If that works then you might have to add the order statement to your query string.

Comment: Also in this guide https://thorben-janssen.com/ordering-vs-sorting-hibernate-use/ under the "Ordering" section, you can see an example that is almost exactly the same as yours and it does seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

I've found out that the instance of EntityManager should be closed after data is inserted and a new instance should be created when fetching data back.

```
EntityManager em = helper.createEntityManager();

// insert data

em.close();

em = helper.createEntityManager();

// fetch data
```